# cakephp - I want some words to be restricted in my website

Tags: cakephp, words

I want that admin can enter some words which he wants to be restrcted throughout the website. How can I do so?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "throughout the website". What kind of website do you have?

Comment: This sounds like you would like to blacklist a selection of words such as a profanity filter. Is that what you are hinting at?

Comment: Sorry for delay in response Matt Stephens, this is exactly what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a table with forbidden words which you can check any text entry of users with. 
AFAIK there is no ready solution for this, but this is how I would do it. 
For your admin you can write an admin interface with which he/she can add or delete words.